# Adding live population to my Html website from worldometers.info

Tags: html, css, live, population

I have a website that shows the user the population for the country in an attractive way.

My problem is that I will need to get the data to be updated automatically.

My question is how do I get the source code of the population from this website.
https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/afghanistan-population/

Comment: Hello @mohamed and welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest that you read through [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then work on your question accordingly. It would be more optimal to see what you have already tried and what you explicitly failed at.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [following free API](https://rapidapi.com/aldair.sr99/api/world-population) to get the current population of the country. Then you can use JavaScript to fetch the value and output it on your website. To always display the latest value, you could wrap the fetch method in an interval, which repeats after a given time.

Comment: FYI: You can accept the answer that solved your problem. (meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).